# Origin header in Chrome Extension

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, header, same-origin-policy

I have my api running on node js, where for security reasons, I have set up a middle ware function check the origin header, if it is from my website, then only the api should go ahead. I am finding issues with Chrome Extension, as it does not pass the origin header in the get requests, also in the put requests, it sends something like chrome:// as the origin header. Can somebody help?

Regards,
Manik Mittal

Comment: I guess you're receiving the local URI of your extension as the origin. Try adding that to your middleware function.

Comment: try giving permission in manifest file to your local API (http://* )

Comment: If you put `http://*` you'll get an error `Permission 'http://*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.` Use `http://*/` instead. Also keep in mind if is possible to use https with `https://*/`

Answer (score 5):

Well, that's how Chrome sets the `Origin` for extensions. It's not simple to override.

It is, however, *possible* to override. You'll need to use the [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), specifically a blocking response to `onBeforeSendHeaders`, to rewrite the origin to whatever you like.

Answer (score -1):

If you add in your `manifest.json` "permissions": ["https://*/"] you shouldn't have problems with CORS. Or if you want only your API to avoid this, just add your own url.

Comment: permissions in `manifest.json` only fix CORS for background script and browser actions (such as popup), but not for content script

Comment: Also don't set it to `*/*`, just set it to the domain you want to so `https://api.example.com/*`